# How to create table that displays attributes of objects using Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to make a search that displays results from a SQLAlchemy database query to my users. However, it seems as though what's being returned is an empty list - the table has a header but not other rows. I've checked to make sure I'm getting results, so I don't know what's going wrong. I've tried sending the data in it's original form and as a list of dictionaries but still haven't had any luck. Any insights?

```
for result in results:
    resultData = {'system_name':result.system_name,'system_description':result.system_description,'system_tags':[tag.tag_name for tag in result.tags],'system_date_created':result.system_date_created,'system_hits':result.system_hits}
    response.append(resultData)
print response
return render_template('index.html', searchResults=response)
```

### index.html

```
<table class='table table-hover'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Tags</th>
<th>Date Created</th>
<th>Views</th>
</tr>
{% for result in searchResults %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ result.system_name }}</td>
    <td>{{ result.system_description }}</td>
    <td>Tags</td>
    <td>{{ result.system_date_created }}</td>
    <td>{{ result.system_hits }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: debugging tips: 1. can you try to Jsonify() the results, 2. also first try after the for loop {{result}} and what do you get?.

Comment: can you check your requirements.txt file to see if you have Jinja?

Comment: As I was testing I realized none of the templating language was actually being executed; I added `text = "hi"` to the render_template attributes and `{{ text }}` in one of my elements and it didn't appear

Comment: However, the templating does appear on some of my other returns, such as my default one (if no other returns are successful it does `render_template('index.html', text='unchanged')`, and I saw the "unchanged" appear. So I'm pretty sure I have Jinja

Comment: okay instead of assigning a new dict to the values in resultData, how about if you return just result to the template

Comment: Also unsuccessful. I may work around it by sending my response to my success function in jQuery and having jQuery create the table, but it seems like something that should be feasible, even easy, using jinja

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick example for serving up an html table from some nested data. As suggested, there's also an extra endpoint with jsonify data for debugging.

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import namedtupled as nt  # for debugging 

app = Flask(__name__)

# set up some fake data
foo = { 'system_name': 'foo', 'system_description': 'bar',
        'tags': [{'tag_name': 'happy'}, {'tag_name': 'cat'}],
        'system_date_created': 'today', 'system_hits': 100 }
fuu = { 'system_name': 'fuu', 'system_description': 'bor',
        'tags': [{'tag_name': 'cute'}, {'tag_name': 'puppy'}],
        'system_date_created': 'yesterday', 'system_hits': 99 }

# make fake data classy so it fits your example
results = [nt.map(foo), nt.map(fuu)]  

def refine_results(results):
    """ Refine some search results. """
    # something here, maybe a request for search results
    data = []
    for result in results:
        resultData = {'system_name': result.system_name,
                      'system_description': result.system_description,
                      'system_tags': [tag.tag_name for tag in result.tags],
                      'system_date_created': result.system_date_created,
                      'system_hits': result.system_hits}
        data.append(resultData)
    return data

@app.route('/json')
def data():
    """ Extra endpoint for debugging expected data. """
    searchResults = refine_results(results)
    return jsonify(searchResults)

@app.route('/table')
def table():
    """ html table with data """
    searchResults = refine_results(results)
    return render_template('index.html', searchResults=searchResults)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Tags</th>
    <th>Date Created</th>
    <th>Views</th>
  </tr>
  {% for result in searchResults %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ result.system_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ result.system_description }}</td>
        <td>
          {% for tag in result.system_tags %}
            {{tag}}
          {% endfor %}
        </td>
        <td>{{ result.system_date_created }}</td>
        <td>{{ result.system_hits }}</td>
      </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```